# Can initialPlaybackTime do not preform animation?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller

As i use `initialPlaybackTime` when playback a movie,the thumb show a animation from the beginning to where i set my `initialPlaybackTime`,but i do not like this at all ,could i enable it?